# pad creation and some mistakes on gst_parse_launch

Tags: gstreamer

I am a newbie to gstreamer and I would like to know if we have to create source and sink pads for convert like video convert in a pipeline. I have a pipeline like this

```
gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src ! video/x-raw,format=YUY2 !  videoconvert ! xvimagesink
```

I am trying to create a simple c application to understand the creation of pads and would like to know if video convert has a source pad and sink pad too. I am creating a source and sink pad for the filter.

EDIT:
yeah well you see, I tried following the dynamic pipelines example and wrote the code below

```
#include <gst/gst.h>


// easier to pass them as callbacks
typedef struct _CustomData{
  GstElement *pipeline;
  GstElement *source;
  GstElement *convert;
  GstElement *sink;
}CustomData;

// callback function

// here src is the v4l2src, newpad is gstpad that has just been added to src element. This is usually the pad to which we want to lnk
// data is the pointer we provided when attaching to the signal.

static void pad_added_handler(GstElement *src, GstPad *new_pad,CustomData *data)
{
  g_print("In pad handler\n");
  GstPad *sink_pad = gst_element_get_static_pad(data->convert, "sink");
  GstPadLinkReturn ret;
  GstCaps *new_pad_caps = NULL;
  GstStructure *new_pad_struct = NULL;
  const gchar *new_pad_type = NULL;

  if(gst_pad_is_linked(sink_pad))
    {
      g_print("we are linked. igonring\n");
    }
  // check the new pad types
  // we have previously created a piece of pipeline which deals with videoconvert linked with xvimagesink and we will nto be able to link it to a pad producing video.
  //gst-pad_get_current_caps()- retrieves current capabilities of pad 
    new_pad_caps = gst_pad_get_current_caps(new_pad);
    new_pad_struct = gst_caps_get_structure(new_pad_caps, 0);
    new_pad_type = gst_structure_get_name(new_pad_struct);
     g_print ("It has type '%s' which is not raw audio. Ignoring.\n", new_pad_type);

     if(!g_str_has_prefix(new_pad_type, "video/x-raw,format=(string)YUY2"))
     {
         g_print("It has new pad type");
      }

  // gst_pad_link tries to link two pads . the link must be specified from source to sink and both pads must be owned by elements residing in same pipeline
  ret = gst_pad_link(new_pad, sink_pad);
  if(GST_PAD_LINK_FAILED(ret))
    {
      g_print("type is new_pad_type");
    }
  if(new_pad_caps !=NULL)
    {
      gst_caps_unref(new_pad_caps);
        }
    gst_object_unref(sink_pad);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  GMainLoop *loop;
  CustomData data;
    GstBus *bus;
  GstMessage *msg;
  gboolean terminate = FALSE;
  gst_init(&argc, &argv);
  //  loop = g_main_loop_new(NULL, FALSE);
  // create the elements
  data.source = gst_element_factory_make("v4l2src", "source");
  data.convert = gst_element_factory_make("videoconvert", "convert");
  data.sink = gst_element_factory_make("xvimagesink", "sink");

  data.pipeline = gst_pipeline_new("new-pipeline");

  if(!data.pipeline || !data.source || !data.convert || !data.sink)
    {
      g_printerr("Not all elements could be created\n");
      return -1;
    }

  //we did not link source at this point of time, we will do it later
  gst_bin_add_many(GST_BIN(data.pipeline), data.source, data.convert, data.sink, NULL);
  // we link convert element to sink, do not link them with source. we dont have source pads here. so we just have videoconvert->sink unlinked
  //    gst_element_link(data.source, data.convert);
  if(!gst_element_link( data.convert,data.sink))
    {
      g_printerr("elements could not be linked\n");
      gst_object_unref(data.pipeline);
      return -1;
    }

  // we set the device source
  //g_object_set(source, "device", "/dev/video0", NULL);

  //connect to pad added signal.
  // we want to attach pad added signal to source element. to do so, we are using g_signal_connect and provide callback function and datapointer.
  // when source element has enough information to start producing data, it will create source pads and trigger the pad added signal. at this point, our callback is called
  g_print("before signal connect\n");
        gint id= g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(data.source), "pad-added", G_CALLBACK(pad_added_handler), &data );
    g_print("after signal connect with id = %d\n", id);
  //g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(data.source), "pad-added", G_CALLBACK(handler), &data);
    //   gst_element_link(data.source, data.convert);
     GstStateChangeReturn ret;
  ret =gst_element_set_state (data.pipeline, GST_STATE_PLAYING);
   if (ret == GST_STATE_CHANGE_FAILURE) {
    g_printerr ("Unable to set the pipeline to the playing state.\n");
    gst_object_unref (data.pipeline);
    return -1;
    }
   //   g_main_loop_run(loop);
    /* Listen to the bus */
  bus = gst_element_get_bus (data.pipeline);
  do {
    msg = gst_bus_timed_pop_filtered (bus, GST_CLOCK_TIME_NONE,
        GST_MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGED | GST_MESSAGE_ERROR | GST_MESSAGE_EOS);

    /* Parse message */
    if (msg != NULL) {
      GError *err;
      gchar *debug_info;

      switch (GST_MESSAGE_TYPE (msg)) {
        case GST_MESSAGE_ERROR:
          gst_message_parse_error (msg, &err, &debug_info);
          g_printerr ("Error received from element %s: %s\n", GST_OBJECT_NAME (msg->src), err->message);
          g_printerr ("Debugging information: %s\n", debug_info ? debug_info : "none");
          g_clear_error (&err);
          g_free (debug_info);
          terminate = TRUE;
          break;
        case GST_MESSAGE_EOS:
          g_print ("End-Of-Stream reached.\n");
          terminate = TRUE;
          break;
        case GST_MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGED:
          /* We are only interested in state-changed messages from the pipeline */
          if (GST_MESSAGE_SRC (msg) == GST_OBJECT (data.pipeline)) {
            GstState old_state, new_state, pending_state;
            gst_message_parse_state_changed (msg, &old_state, &new_state, &pending_state);
            g_print ("Pipeline state changed from %s to %s:\n",
                gst_element_state_get_name (old_state), gst_element_state_get_name (new_state));
          }
          break;
        default:
          /* We should not reach here */
          g_printerr ("Unexpected message received.\n");
          break;
      }
      gst_message_unref (msg);
    }
  } while (!terminate);

  /* Free resources */
  gst_object_unref (bus);

  gst_element_set_state(data.pipeline, GST_STATE_NULL);
  gst_object_unref(data.pipeline);
  return 0;
}
```

and it gave me an error

```
before signal connect
after signal connect with id = 1
Pipeline state changed from NULL to READY:
Pipeline state changed from READY to PAUSED:
Error received from element source: Internal data stream error.
Debugging information: gstbasesrc.c(3055): gst_base_src_loop (): /GstPipeline:new-pipeline/GstV4l2Src:source:
streaming stopped, reason not-linked (-1)
```

(The above code works if I write gst_elements_link(data.source, data.convert) after the element link statement for convert and sink)

So I tried the normal way in which I just added and linked all the elements together and it began to work without use of the pads.

```
#include <gst/gst.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  GstElement *pipeline, *source, *convert, *sink;
  GstBus *bus;
  GstMessage *msg;

  gst_init(&argc, &argv);

  source = gst_element_factory_make("v4l2src", "source");
  convert = gst_element_factory_make("nvvidconv", "convert");
  sink = gst_element_factory_make("xvimagesink", "sink");

  pipeline = gst_pipeline_new("pipe");

  gst_bin_add_many(GST_BIN(pipeline), source,convert,sink, NULL);
  gst_element_link_many(source,convert,sink,NULL);
  gst_element_set_state(pipeline,GST_STATE_PLAYING);



bus = gst_element_get_bus (pipeline);
  msg = gst_bus_timed_pop_filtered (bus, GST_CLOCK_TIME_NONE, GST_MESSAGE_ERROR | GST_MESSAGE_EOS);

  /* Parse message */
  if (msg != NULL) {
    GError *err;
    gchar *debug_info;

    switch (GST_MESSAGE_TYPE (msg)) {
      case GST_MESSAGE_ERROR:
        gst_message_parse_error (msg, &err, &debug_info);
        g_printerr ("Error received from element %s: %s\n", GST_OBJECT_NAME (msg->src), err->message);
        g_printerr ("Debugging information: %s\n", debug_info ? debug_info : "none");
        g_clear_error (&err);
        g_free (debug_info);
        break;
      case GST_MESSAGE_EOS:
        g_print ("End-Of-Stream reached.\n");
        break;
      default:
        /* We should not reach here because we only asked for ERRORs and EOS */
        g_printerr ("Unexpected message received.\n");
        break;
    }
    gst_message_unref (msg);
  }

  /* Free resources */
  gst_object_unref(bus);

  gst_element_set_state(pipeline,GST_STATE_NULL);
  gst_object_unref(pipeline);

}
```

But, inorder to fully grasp the knowledge of pads, I wanted to execute simpler pipelines with pads. 
I just don't fully understand the usage of pads and link them and all.

EDIT2:

Ultimately I want to write application for pipeline like this which works on command line perfectly well,

```
gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src device='/dev/video0' ! 'video/x-raw,format=(string)YUY2,width=(int)640,height=(int)480' ! nvvidconv ! 'video/x-raw(memory:NVMM),format=(string)NV12,width=(int)640,height=(int)480' ! nvvidconv ! 'video/x-raw,format=(string)NV12,width=(int)640,height=(int)480' ! nvvideoconvert ! 'video/x-raw(memory:NVMM),format=(string)NV12,width=(int)640,height=(int)480' ! mux.sink_0 nvstreammux live-source=1 name=mux batch-size=1 width=640 height=480 ! nvinfer config-file-path=/opt/nvidia/deepstream/deepstream-4.0/sources/apps/sample_apps/deepstream-test1/dstest1_pgie_config.txt batch-size=1 ! nvmultistreamtiler rows=1 columns=1 width=640 height=480 ! nvvideoconvert ! nvdsosd ! nvegltransform ! nveglglessink sync=false -v
```

But as I don't understand the usage of both pads and bins, I am unable to implement them in my above pipeline. However, I tried this,

```
#include <gst/gst.h>
#include <glib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "gstnvdsmeta.h"


#define MAX_DISPLAY_LEN 64

#define PGIE_CLASS_ID_VEHICLE 0
#define PGIE_CLASS_ID_PERSON 2

gint frame_number = 0;
gchar pgie_classes_str[4][32] = { "Vehicle", "TwoWheeler", "Person",
  "Roadsign"
};


static GstPadProbeReturn osd_sink_pad_buffer_probe(GstPad *pad, GstPadProbeInfo *info, gpointer u_data)
{
  GstBuffer *buf=(GstBuffer *)info->data;
  guint num_rects =0;
  NvDsObjectMeta *obj_meta = NULL;
    guint vehicle_count = 0;
    guint person_count = 0;
    NvDsMetaList * l_frame = NULL;
    NvDsMetaList * l_obj = NULL;
    NvDsDisplayMeta *display_meta = NULL;

    NvDsBatchMeta *batch_meta = gst_buffer_get_nvds_batch_meta (buf);

    for (l_frame = batch_meta->frame_meta_list; l_frame != NULL;
      l_frame = l_frame->next) {
        NvDsFrameMeta *frame_meta = (NvDsFrameMeta *) (l_frame->data);
        int offset = 0;
        for (l_obj = frame_meta->obj_meta_list; l_obj != NULL;
                l_obj = l_obj->next) {
            obj_meta = (NvDsObjectMeta *) (l_obj->data);
            if (obj_meta->class_id == PGIE_CLASS_ID_VEHICLE) {
                vehicle_count++;
                num_rects++;
            }
            if (obj_meta->class_id == PGIE_CLASS_ID_PERSON) {
                person_count++;
                num_rects++;
            }
        }
        display_meta = nvds_acquire_display_meta_from_pool(batch_meta);
        NvOSD_TextParams *txt_params  = &display_meta->text_params[0];
        display_meta->num_labels = 1;
        txt_params->display_text = g_malloc0 (MAX_DISPLAY_LEN);
        offset = snprintf(txt_params->display_text, MAX_DISPLAY_LEN, "Person = %d ", person_count);
        offset = snprintf(txt_params->display_text + offset , MAX_DISPLAY_LEN, "Vehicle = %d ", vehicle_count);

        /* Now set the offsets where the string should appear */
        txt_params->x_offset = 10;
        txt_params->y_offset = 12;

        /* Font , font-color and font-size */
        txt_params->font_params.font_name = "Serif";
        txt_params->font_params.font_size = 10;
        txt_params->font_params.font_color.red = 1.0;
        txt_params->font_params.font_color.green = 1.0;
        txt_params->font_params.font_color.blue = 1.0;
        txt_params->font_params.font_color.alpha = 1.0;

        /* Text background color */
        txt_params->set_bg_clr = 1;
        txt_params->text_bg_clr.red = 0.0;
        txt_params->text_bg_clr.green = 0.0;
        txt_params->text_bg_clr.blue = 0.0;
        txt_params->text_bg_clr.alpha = 1.0;

        nvds_add_display_meta_to_frame(frame_meta, display_meta);
    }

    g_print ("Frame Number = %d Number of objects = %d "
            "Vehicle Count = %d Person Count = %d\n",
            frame_number, num_rects, vehicle_count, person_count);
    frame_number++;
    return GST_PAD_PROBE_OK;

}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   GstElement *pipeline,  *source, *filter1, *convert,*filter2, *filter3, *vidconv, *filter4, *mux, *infer, *tiler, *osd, *transform , *sink, *bin, *convert2 , *vidconv2;
   GMainLoop *loop;
   GstCaps *caps1, *caps2, *caps3, *caps4;
   GstPad *osd_sink_pad =NULL, *srcpad, *sinkpad;


   loop = g_main_loop_new(NULL,FALSE);
   gst_init(&argc, &argv);
   pipeline = gst_pipeline_new("nv_pipeline");
   gchar *string1 = "video/x-raw(memory:NVMM),format=(string)NV12";

   source = gst_element_factory_make("v4l2src", "source");
   filter1 = gst_element_factory_make("capsfilter", "filter1");
   convert = gst_element_factory_make("nvvidconv", "convert");
   filter2 = gst_element_factory_make("capsfilter", "filter2");
   filter3 = gst_element_factory_make("capsfilter", "filter3");
   filter4 = gst_element_factory_make("capsfilter", "filter4");
   vidconv = gst_element_factory_make("nvvideoconvert", "vidconv");
   mux = gst_element_factory_make("nvstreammux", "mux");
   infer = gst_element_factory_make("nvinfer", "infer");
   tiler = gst_element_factory_make("nvmultistreamtiler", "tiler");
   osd = gst_element_factory_make("nvosd", "osd");
   transform = gst_element_factory_make("nvegltransform", "transform");
   sink = gst_element_factory_make("nveglglessink", "sink");
   convert2 = gst_element_factory_make("nvvidconv", "convert2");
   vidconv2 = gst_element_factory_make("nvvideoconvert", "vidconv2");

   gst_bin_add_many(GST_BIN(pipeline), source,filter1,convert,filter2, convert2,filter3,vidconv, filter4,mux,infer, tiler,vidconv2, osd,transform,sink,NULL);

   gst_element_link_many(source,filter1,convert,filter2, convert2,filter3, vidconv, filter4,mux,infer, tiler,vidconv2, osd,transform,sink,NULL);

   osd_sink_pad = gst_element_get_static_pad(osd, "sink");
   gst_pad_add_probe(osd_sink_pad, GST_PAD_PROBE_TYPE_BUFFER, osd_sink_pad_buffer_probe, NULL, NULL);

   caps1 = gst_caps_new_simple("video/x-raw", "format",G_TYPE_STRING,"YUY2",NULL);
   caps2 = gst_caps_from_string(string1);
   caps3 = gst_caps_new_simple("video/x-raw", "format", G_TYPE_STRING,"NV12", NULL);
   caps4 = gst_caps_from_string(string1);

   g_object_set(G_OBJECT(filter1), "caps", caps1, NULL);
   g_object_set(G_OBJECT(filter2), "caps", caps2, NULL);
   g_object_set(G_OBJECT(filter3), "caps", caps3, NULL);
   g_object_set(G_OBJECT(filter4), "caps", caps4, NULL);

   g_object_set(G_OBJECT(mux), "live-source", 1, "name", "mux", "batch-size", 1, "width", 1280, "height", 720, NULL);
   g_object_set(G_OBJECT(infer), "config-file-path","/opt/nvidia/deepstream/deepstream-4.0/sources/apps/sample_apps/deepstream-test1/dstest1_pgie_config.txt",NULL);
   g_object_set(G_OBJECT(infer), "batch-size", 1, NULL);
   g_object_set(G_OBJECT(tiler), "rows", 1, "columns", 1, "width", 1280, "height", 720, NULL);

   gst_caps_unref(caps1);
   gst_caps_unref(caps2);
   gst_caps_unref(caps3);
   gst_caps_unref(caps4);

   gst_element_set_state(pipeline, GST_STATE_PLAYING);
   g_print("Running ...\n");
   g_main_loop_run(loop);

   gst_element_set_state(pipeline,GST_STATE_NULL);
   gst_object_unref(pipeline);
   return 0;
}
```

which gives the exact same output as the command line gst-launch-1.0 like,

```
(deep_pads:15648): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: 11:29:18.761: cannot register existing type 'GstInterpolationMethod'

(deep_pads:15648): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 11:29:18.761: g_param_spec_enum: assertion 'G_TYPE_IS_ENUM (enum_type)' failed

(deep_pads:15648): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 11:29:18.761: validate_pspec_to_install: assertion 'G_IS_PARAM_SPEC (pspec)' failed

(deep_pads:15648): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 11:29:18.814: gst_element_get_static_pad: assertion 'GST_IS_ELEMENT (element)' failed

(deep_pads:15648): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 11:29:18.814: gst_pad_add_probe: assertion 'GST_IS_PAD (pad)' failed
0:00:00.843318172 15648   0x5591be52c0 INFO                 nvinfer gstnvinfer.cpp:519:gst_nvinfer_logger:<infer> NvDsInferContext[UID 1]:initialize(): Trying to create engine from model files
0:00:20.693301580 15648   0x5591be52c0 INFO                 nvinfer gstnvinfer.cpp:519:gst_nvinfer_logger:<infer> NvDsInferContext[UID 1]:generateTRTModel(): Storing the serialized cuda engine to file at /opt/nvidia/deepstream/deepstream-4.0/samples/models/Primary_Detector/resnet10.caffemodel_b1_int8.engine
```

except It doesn't display an output window from the above c application and doesn't display the rest.

Comment: So you are basically asking - how to write hello world C code with GStreamer? This is not what you ask on SO :) Just do a quick search, go through the tutorials and find out yourself. Start with these tutorials, this one has some walk through.
https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/tutorials/basic/concepts.html?gi-language=c
You can also check the PADS creation process in detail if you enable debug logs with `GST_DEBUG=GST_PADS:5 gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src ....`

Comment: @nayana please look at the above edit and please help. Thanks!

Comment: Oh and I also tried adding the edit2 pipeline in gst-parse-launch from c application and it is so weird that it doesn't work but it works on command line. It doesn't work as in, I get the same output as the c application one.  So, I don't know what I am missing basically. @nayana

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first example fails because `data.source` element is actually never linked to `data.convert` element. Since both elements have **static** pads you need to "manually" create them and link them before setting pipeline to `GST_STATE_PLAYING`:

```
GstPad *source_pad = gst_element_get_static_pad(data.source, "src");
GstPad *sink_pad = gst_element_get_static_pad(data.convert, "sink");
ret = gst_pad_link(source_pad, sink_pad);
```

You probably expected that static source pad of your `data.source` element will somehow be automatically created so you registered

```
g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(data.source), "pad-added", G_CALLBACK(pad_added_handler), &data );
```

But, as you can see from your debug, **`pad_added_handler` was never called** because `g_signal_connect` can be registered and will be called for elements that have [dynamic pads](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/application-development/basics/pads.html?gi-language=c#dynamic-or-sometimes-pads). For example, demultiplexer `tsdemux` will dynamically create its source pads during discovery of elementary streams so, in that case, registration of `pad-added` callback would be necessary.

The first step in your learning curve would be to understand fundamental differences between **"static"** (mandatory, always exists, "manually" created), **dynamic** (exists sometimes, automatically created by element) and **request** (optional, "manually" created when needed) gstreamer [pads](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/application-development/basics/pads.html?gi-language=c#). After that everything will be much easier for you.

Comment: Thank you so much for helping. It is clear what I missed in the first example and I am able to understand my mistake now. And I should check the pad availability using gst-inspect right? I got it now. Thank you! And also, any idea, why when I write my pipeline in edit2 to gst_parse_launch, it doesn't display any window? but it works on command line?

Comment: @lorugant ,  you are welcome. Regarding launch command... question becomes so broad and SO readers will not be able to follow it. My suggestion: delete edit 3 and create another question for gst launch specifically. Also mark this answer somehow if it was helpfull.

Comment: ok. Here is the link to edit 3 [edit 3 question] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59427179/gst-parse-launch-differs-output-from-command-line-gst-launch)

Comment: no. nevermind. I got the gst_parse_launch to work and wrote the answer in the above link. But @Dusan Kovacevic  can you please have a look at (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59429894/realtime-v4l2src-for-deepstream-test1-c-application-does-not-work) which depends on both gstreamer and deepstream. The c code is based on deepstream example deepstream-test1 and deepstream-segmentation.Thanks!