# gst_parse_launch differs output from command line gst_launch

Tags: gstreamer, gstreamer-1.0

I have a pipeline like this, which works with gst-launch-1.0

```
gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src device='/dev/video0' ! 'video/x-raw,format=(string)YUY2,width=(int)640,height=(int)480' ! nvvidconv ! 'video/x-raw(memory:NVMM),format=(string)NV12,width=(int)640,height=(int)480' ! nvvidconv ! 'video/x-raw,format=(string)NV12,width=(int)640,height=(int)480' ! nvvideoconvert ! 'video/x-raw(memory:NVMM),format=(string)NV12,width=(int)640,height=(int)480' ! mux.sink_0 nvstreammux live-source=1 name=mux batch-size=1 width=640 height=480 ! nvinfer config-file-path=/opt/nvidia/deepstream/deepstream-4.0/sources/apps/sample_apps/deepstream-test1/dstest1_pgie_config.txt batch-size=1 ! nvmultistreamtiler rows=1 columns=1 width=640 height=480 ! nvvideoconvert ! nvdsosd ! nvegltransform ! nveglglessink sync=false -v
```

In my c application, such as below which executes the same command line, it doesn't display any window.

```
#include <gst/gst.h>

int
main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  GstElement *pipeline;
  GstBus *bus;
  GstMessage *msg;

  /* Initialize GStreamer */
  gst_init (&argc, &argv);

  /* Build the pipeline */
  pipeline =
      gst_parse_launch
      ("v4l2src device='/dev/video0' ! 'video/x-raw,format=(string)YUY2,width=(int)640,height=(int)480' ! nvvidconv ! 'video/x-raw(memory:NVMM),format=(string)NV12,width=(int)640,height=(int)480' ! nvvidconv ! 'video/x-raw,format=(string)NV12,width=(int)640,height=(int)480' ! nvvideoconvert ! 'video/x-raw(memory:NVMM),format=(string)NV12,width=(int)640,height=(int)480' ! mux.sink_0 nvstreammux live-source=1 name=mux batch-size=1 width=640 height=480 ! nvinfer config-file-path=/opt/nvidia/deepstream/deepstream-4.0/sources/apps/sample_apps/deepstream-test1/dstest1_pgie_config.txt batch-size=1 ! nvmultistreamtiler rows=1 columns=1 width=640 height=480 ! nvvideoconvert ! nvdsosd ! nvegltransform ! nveglglessink sync=false -v",
      NULL);

  /* Start playing */
  gst_element_set_state (pipeline, GST_STATE_PLAYING);

  /* Wait until error or EOS */
  bus = gst_element_get_bus (pipeline);
  msg =
      gst_bus_timed_pop_filtered (bus, GST_CLOCK_TIME_NONE,
      GST_MESSAGE_ERROR | GST_MESSAGE_EOS);

  /* Free resources */
  if (msg != NULL)
    gst_message_unref (msg);
  gst_object_unref (bus);
  gst_element_set_state (pipeline, GST_STATE_NULL);
  gst_object_unref (pipeline);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's why you should check for errors. You pipeline description has a `-v` at the end which is an option to the `gst-launch-1.0` application but is not part of a valid pipeline description.

Comment: I tried both with -v and without -v and it works both times. I don't know why though.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the mistake in the above code. In the caps filter, there is no quotes. and the rest works fine.

```
#include <gst/gst.h>

int
main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  GstElement *pipeline;
  GstBus *bus;
  GstMessage *msg;

  /* Initialize GStreamer */
  gst_init (&argc, &argv);

  /* Build the pipeline */
  pipeline =
      gst_parse_launch
    ("v4l2src ! video/x-raw,format=(string)YUY2 ! nvvidconv ! video/x-raw(memory:NVMM),format=(string)NV12 ! nvvidconv ! video/x-raw,format=(string)NV12 ! nvvideoconvert ! video/x-raw(memory:NVMM),format=(string)NV12 ! mux.sink_0 nvstreammux live-source=1 name=mux batch-size=1 width=640 height=480 ! nvinfer config-file-path=/opt/nvidia/deepstream/deepstream-4.0/sources/apps/sample_apps/deepstream-test1/dstest1_pgie_config.txt batch-size=1 ! nvmultistreamtiler rows=1 columns=1 width=640 height=480 ! nvvideoconvert ! nvdsosd ! nvegltransform ! nveglglessink", NULL);

  /* Start playing */
  gst_element_set_state (pipeline, GST_STATE_PLAYING);

  /* Wait until error or EOS */
  bus = gst_element_get_bus (pipeline);
  msg =
      gst_bus_timed_pop_filtered (bus, GST_CLOCK_TIME_NONE,
      GST_MESSAGE_ERROR | GST_MESSAGE_EOS);

  /* Free resources */
  if (msg != NULL)
    gst_message_unref (msg);
  gst_object_unref (bus);
  gst_element_set_state (pipeline, GST_STATE_NULL);
  gst_object_unref (pipeline);
  return 0;
}
```

This above code works for me in nvidia xavier!

Answer (score 0):

**TLDR**

In function `gst_parse_launch (const gchar * pipeline_description, GError ** error)`, the `pipeline_description` string should follow the following rules.

1. Element properties' value should not be quoted with single quotes (`'`)

   > For example, `v4l2src device='/dev/video'` will cause an error since `'` is part of the device name and GStreamer cannot identify device `'/dev/video0'`.
2. Element or caps string between `!` should not be quoted.

   > For example, both `'image/jpeg,width=640,height=480,framerate=30/1'` and `"image/jpeg,width=640,height=480,framerate=30/1"` will cause a parse error.

---

Here is a C example:

```
#include <gst/gst.h>

int tutorial_main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    GstElement* pipeline;
    GstBus* bus;
    GstMessage* msg;

    /* Initialize GStreamer */
    gst_init(&argc, &argv);

    /* Build the pipeline */
    pipeline = gst_parse_launch(
        "v4l2src device='/dev/video0' ! "
        "image/jpeg,width=640,height=480,framerate=30/1 ! "
        "avdec_mjpeg ! "
        "videoconvert ! "
        "autovideosink",
        NULL);

    /* Start playing */
    gst_element_set_state(pipeline, GST_STATE_PLAYING);

    /* Wait until error or EOS */
    bus = gst_element_get_bus(pipeline);
    msg = gst_bus_timed_pop_filtered(bus, GST_CLOCK_TIME_NONE,
        GST_MESSAGE_ERROR | GST_MESSAGE_EOS);

    /* See next tutorial for proper error message handling/parsing */
    if (GST_MESSAGE_TYPE(msg) == GST_MESSAGE_ERROR) {
        g_error("An error occurred! Re-run with the GST_DEBUG=*:WARN environment "
                "variable set for more details.");
    }

    /* Free resources */
    gst_message_unref(msg);
    gst_object_unref(bus);
    gst_element_set_state(pipeline, GST_STATE_NULL);
    gst_object_unref(pipeline);
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    return tutorial_main(argc, argv);
}
```

This C code is just equivalent to the following shell command

```bash
gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src device="'/dev/video0'" ! image/jpeg,width=640,height=480,framerate=30/1 ! avdec_mjpeg ! videoconvert ! autovideosink
```

If we set `GST_DEBUG=*:WARN`, we can see the error message:

```bash
$ export GST_DEBUG=*:WARN
$ gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src device="'/dev/video0'" ! image/jpeg,width=640,height=480,framerate=30/1 ! avdec_mjpeg ! videoconvert ! autovideosink
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
0:00:00.370062578 18657 0x557ff3bfb780 WARN                 default v4l2-utils.c:189:gst_v4l2_error:<v4l2src0> error: Cannot identify device ''/dev/video0''.
0:00:00.370079963 18657 0x557ff3bfb780 WARN                 default v4l2-utils.c:192:gst_v4l2_error:<v4l2src0> error: system error: No such file or directory
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstV4l2Src:v4l2src0: Cannot identify device ''/dev/video0''.
Additional debug info:
../gstreamer/subprojects/gst-plugins-good/sys/v4l2/v4l2_calls.c(612): gst_v4l2_open (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstV4l2Src:v4l2src0:
system error: No such file or directory
ERROR: pipeline doesn't want to preroll.
Failed to set pipeline to PAUSED.
Setting pipeline to NULL ...
Freeing pipeline ...
```